# What are appropriate imputation methods for handling missing data in the case of censored distribution?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I measured antibodies in blood with a test kit that gives quantitative values between 2 and 20 mg/mL. All values below 2 are indicated as <2 and values above 20 are indicated as >20 (the test does not give any quantitative value <2 and >20). I want to compare this test kit with a reference method (which is not censored) as well as other test kits (which are not censored as well) and do quantitative statistical analyses.

My question is: How can I deal with the test kit values <2 and >20? I wonder if there are appropriate methods for imputation. For example, I know from experience in my field that antibody values cannot be lower than 0 and most often go up to 30 maximum. Is it appropriate to randomly assign values between 0 and 2 for measurements indicated as <2 and randomly assign values between 20 and 30 for measurements indicated as >20?

Or is it better to delete the incomplete records altogether instead of trying to impute?

Comment: The best (and usual) techniques do not attempt imputation, but instead use either nonparametric techniques or distributional assumptions.  The latter are equivalent to certain forms of random assignment.  Deleting the incomplete records is one of the worst things you can do.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcensoring%5D+calibration.

Comment: I understand that it's not appropriate to delete incomplete records when we want for example to study the population characteristics (mean, SD, etc of antibodies in a given population). In this case, methods like nonparametric techniques/distributional assumptions are useful. In my case, I want to assess the performances of the test kit for predicting antibodies using e.g. correlations and Bland-Altman plots (is the test kit accurate enough compared to a reference method and to other existing methods?). What is the best approach in this case (deleting incomplete records/imputation/other?)?